# Is it possible to do HTTP2 without header compression (HPack)?

Tags: http2

Is it possible to somehow disable header compression from the server side in HTTP2? For both the client-to-server and server-to-client communication. E.g. by setting compression table size to zero, or something? Perhaps only using the static table?

(This would simplify implementation considerably, which would be more in line with the thinking behind HTTP1, simplicity. The other (huge) benefits of HTTP2 would remain. In other words, is HPack mandatory?)

EDIT, rewording for clarity...

Is it possible to, from the server, make it so that no compression is used? This, in order to avoid implementing a complex part of HTTP2. I kind of suspect that it is not possible (because it would essentially make HTTP2 slower). But maybe the client is required to obey some setting from the server, either before (really unlikely because slow) it starts sending compressed data, or if it can restart uncompressed sending after new setting (more likely, I feel).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to disable the compression without setting the table size to zero.

You can choose compression method like; use static table only, use dynamic table only, use huffman encoding, use string literal encoding.

If you send header as string literal (no compression), you have to set flag as so.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is it possible though, to, from the server, make it so that no compression is used? Maybe my question is not clearly enough worded. I kind of suspect that it is not possible (because that would essentially make HTTP2 slower). But maybe the client is required to obey some setting from the server, either before it starts sending compressed data, or if it can restart sending.

Comment: From server, It is not possible to force uncompression. If table size is set to  zero as you mentioned, it can force endpoint not to use 'dynamic table' for compression. Additionaly, the setting can be sent any time for changing the table size.